# How to get the results as a value

Tags: java, mongodb-java, mongo-java

---

I am trying to make a program that finds the coordinate values x and y from the database of mongoDB. After,to subtract these values to find every time their various and to search for the position of the new coordinate.

The structure of the results is for example: offscreen(count): { "x" : "1248" , "y" : "698"}

I have done something but i do not know how to give the values for (x2,x1,y2,y1) or it has better solutions for that.

Thanks for help..

```
            int x_and_y = 1;

            while (cursorEvents.hasNext()) {
            DBObject documentInEventCollection = cursorEvents.next();

            if("mouseMove".equals(documentInEventCollection.get("type"))){ 

            System.out.println("offscreen(" + x_and_y + "): " + documentInEventCollection.get("offScreen").toString());
            x_and_y++;                                      
            }

            if("mouseMove".equals(documentInEventCollection.get("type"))){ 

                if((x2 - x1) < 0 ){

                    System.out.println("Right");

                }else {

                    System.out.println("Left");
                }
                if((y2 - y1) > 0 ){

                    System.out.println("Down");

                }else{

                    System.out.println("Up");                       
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tried to replace your loop while by this :

```
  while (cursorEvents.hasNext()) 
  {
        DBObject doc1 = cursorEvents.next();
        if(cursorEvents.hasNext())
        {
            DBObject doc2 = cursorEvents.next();
        }

        if("mouseMove".equals(documentInEventCollection.get("type"))){ 

        System.out.println("offscreen(" + x_and_y + "): " + doc1.get("offScreen").toString()+","+doc2.get("offScreen").toString());
        x_and_y++;                                      
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes i did it, and after how i will give to the (x2,x1,y2,y1) the values of (offScreen).?

Comment: if you want to set value of x offScreen in x2 for example. You could do that: `DBObject temp = doc1.get("offScreen");` and then `int x2 = (int)temp.get("x");`